# Discord.py bot command to search channel for keywords and copy message to another channel

Tags: python, discord, bots

Edit for follow up Question -

Using the previous suggestion I got it to work.  Then I decided I needed variables with all of the channel ids rather than everyone having to know the IDs.  Is it possible to have the user input be a variable, to where the bot will then use the ID stored in that variable?  I believe it'll work by using a converter.

I've got some code I've pieced together from various sources on here.  My goal is to have a bot command that will search the given channel for a keyword.  Upon finding a message with the keyword in the channel, it will copy that message into another channel then delete the original message.

I'm also trying to do this with user given arguments, so I don't have to change the code for every keyword.

This is what I have so far.

```py
@bot.command()
async def move_information(ctx,Keyword: discord.Message,ChannelFrom: int,ChannelTo: int):
    for message in ChannelFrom:
        msg = await ctx.fetch_mesage(Keyword)
        await ChannelTo.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

discord.message is an object, if you are searching for messages in a specific textchannel then it would be something like this

```py
@bot.command()
async def move_information(ctx,Keyword: str, ChannelFrom: discord.TextChannel, ChannelTo: discord.TextChannel):
    async for message in ChannelFrom.history:
        if Keyword in message.content:
             await ChannelTo.send(Keyword)
```

Comment: I got this to work using your code as a base for it, thank you!


@bot.command()
async def move_information(ctx, Keyword: str, ChannelFrom: discord.TextChannel, ChannelTo: discord.TextChannel):
    messages = await ChannelFrom.history(limit=200).flatten()

    for msg in messages:
        if Keyword in msg.content:
            msend = msg.content
            await ChannelTo.send(msend)
            await msg.delete()